# Odoo model access rule is not working as expected

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

**Model**:-

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

courses = [
    ('mca', "MCA"),
    ('bca', "BCA"),
    ('bsc', "B.Sc"),
    ('msc', "M.Sc"),
    ('btech', "B.Tech"),
    ('mtech', "M.Tech"),
]

class openacademy(models.Model):
    _name = 'openacademy.student'

    name = fields.Char(string="Student Name")
    roll = fields.Integer(string="Roll Number")
    course = fields.Selection(courses, string="Course")
```

**Groups**:-

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="category_openacademy">
    <field name="name">Open Academy</field>
    <field name="sequence">10</field>
</record>

<record id="group_student" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Student</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="category_openacademy"/>
    <field name="comment">Basic access</field>
</record>

<record id="group_teacher" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Teacher</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="category_openacademy"/>
    <field name="comment">Complete Access</field>
</record>
```

**Model Access Rule** (ir.model.access.csv):-

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
ACL_st,oa.ACL_st,model_openacademy_student,group_student,1,0,0,0
ACL_te,oa.ACL_te,model_openacademy_student,group_teacher,1,1,1,1
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,,1,1,1,1
```

Now if a student group user logs into the application then he is able to write/delete records but it has read permission only.

I want that if logged in user don't belongs to any group then he can perform any operation and thats why I added this rule :-

```
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you guess the line:

```
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,,1,1,1,1
```

That one makes students do whatever.

The issue is that group permissions are joined through **OR**. And an user belonging to `group_student` will be affected by both model access lines:

```
ACL_st,oa.ACL_st,model_openacademy_student,group_student,1,0,0,0
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,,1,1,1,1
```

So, as **0 OR 1** is **1**, they can read, create, write and remove.

Therefore, I would do the following:

I would replace the line:

```
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,,1,1,1,1
```

With this line:

```
ACL_ng,oa.ACL_ng,model_openacademy_student,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

That line makes sure that every user can do whatever with `openacademy.student` model.

Now we have to tell Odoo that students can only read, so I would create a rule, which are joined through **AND**.

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="model_openacademy_student_group_student_rule">
    <field name="name">openacademy_student: students can only read</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_openacademy_student"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_student'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

So, as **1 AND 0** is **0**, users belonging to `group_student` would not be allowed to create, write nor remove records from `openacademy.student` model. Rules are applied depending on record values, but with `domain_force` -> `[(1, '=', 1)]` we make sure that every record is affected by our rule.

On the other hand, a standard user (every user belongs to `base.group_user` because the *default user* belongs to it -see `base` module, *base_security.xml*-) would not be affected by the rule, which only applies to `group_student`, so they could still create, write and remove records from `openacademy.student`. And the same with the users belonging to `group_teacher`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If we are not replacing '' with base.group_user in model access rule, will it create any problem ? I am just curious to know.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, I have never tried to leave empty the groups column. In my opinion, that line should be ignored, because it doesn't affect to any group, but reading the behaviour you have described above, I guess is applying it to every group. In that case you wouldn't need to replace the line.